# How can you tell the difference between a text and rich text field with TOM.NET

Tags: tom.net, rtf

From within my (2011 SP1) TBB I need to know when a `TextField` object is rich text or plain text so I can process the contents differently, but I dont see any simple way to find this out. Is this possible without going into the schema XSD?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could check to see if the ItemField type is a XhtmlField.

```
if (itemField is XHtmlField)
{
    // Is Rich Text Field
} 
else if (itemField is TextField)
{
    // Is Text Field
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1! I'd never noticed this ItemField subclass - probably because it's at the bottom of the list. I was poking around in MultiLineTextField and MultiLineTextFieldDefinition for a property of some kind to find an answer to this :)

Comment: Thanks Alex - exactly what I was looking for, very relieved its so simple.